# Import git repository to github

Tags: git, github, import

I have git repo that was on github but it was removed (it was part of the project that was abandoned), I still have a copy and I want to use it as base for other project. Can I import that repo back to github with different name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can, those are just file after all.

Just create the new repo, then commit&push your old project.

Comment: so, should I create new empty repo on github and then change .git/config to point to new repo and commit + push?

Comment: Yes, there's shouldn't be any problem. Thought, I would suggest that you make a backup of you files, so you don't accidentally erase your file if you are unsure about you're doing.